# Gtkmm : Drawing with cairo

Tags: c++, gtk, draw, cairo, gtkmm

Using Gtkmm and Cairo, I want to be able to draw different shapes on photos. In the header bar of my window, I have two buttons representing shapes to draw (circle and rectangle). When you click one of them, you can draw its associated shape. Here is mt code:

**MyWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MyWindow.h"

MyWindow::MyWindow()
        : circleButton("circle"),
          rectangleButton("rectangle ") {

    set_default_size(700, 700);
    set_position(Gtk::WIN_POS_CENTER);

    header.set_show_close_button(true);
    header.pack_start(rectangleButton);
    header.pack_start(circleButton);;

    set_titlebar(header);

    // Dwg is an instance of Drawing class
  
  circleButton.signal_clicked().connect([&] {
        Dwg.switch_to_circle();
    });
    rectangleButton.signal_clicked().connect([&] {
        Dwg.switch_to_rectangle();
    });

    add(Dwg);
    show_all();
}
```

**Drawing.h**

```
#ifndef DRAWING_H
#define DRAWING_H

#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <cairo/cairo.h>

class MyDrawing : public Gtk::Layout {
public:
    MyDrawing();

    ~MyDrawing();

    void switch_to_circle();
    void switch_to_rectangle();

protected:
    virtual bool draw_image(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context> &cr);
    virtual bool draw_rectangle(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context> &cr);
    virtual bool draw_circle(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context> &cr);


private:

    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pix;

    double beginPoint_x, beginPoint_y, endPoint_x, endPoint_y, lineWidth,width,height;

    bool isDrawRectangle;
};

#endif // DRAWING_H
```

**Drawing.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyDrawing.h"
#include <cairomm/context.h>
#include <cairomm/surface.h>


MyDrawing::MyDrawing()
        : isDrawRectangle(true),
          width(20),
          height(20) {

    pix = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("file.svg", 500, 500);
    if (pix) {
        this->signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyDrawing::draw_image));
    }
    add_events(Gdk::BUTTON1_MOTION_MASK | Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

    signal_button_press_event().connect([&](GdkEventButton *e) {
        this->beginPoint_x = e->x;
        this->beginPoint_y = e->y;
        if(isDrawRectangle) {
            this->signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyDrawing::draw_rectangle));
            queue_draw();
        }
        else {
            this->signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyDrawing::draw_circle));
            queue_draw();
        }
        return true;
    });

    signal_motion_notify_event().connect([&](GdkEventMotion *e) {
        this->endPoint_x = e->x;
        this->endPoint_y = e->y;
        width = endPoint_x - beginPoint_x;
        height = endPoint_y - beginPoint_y;

        if(isDrawRectangle) {
            this->signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyDrawing::draw_rectangle));
            queue_draw();
        }
        else {
            this->signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyDrawing::draw_circle));
            queue_draw();
        }

        return true;
    });
}

MyDrawing::~MyDrawing() = default;

bool MyDrawing::draw_image(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context> &cr) {
    std::cout << "signal img" << std::endl;
    if (pix) {
        cr->save();
        Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cr, pix, 100, 100);
        cr->rectangle(0, 0, get_width(), get_height());
        cr->fill();
        cr->restore();
    }
    return false;
}

bool MyDrawing::draw_rectangle(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context> &cr) {
    std::cout << "signal square" << std::endl;
    cr->save();
    cr->set_line_width(10);
    cr->set_source_rgba(0., 0., 1., 1.);
    cr->rectangle(beginPoint_x, beginPoint_y, width, height);
    cr->stroke();
    cr->save();
    cr->restore();

    return false;
}

bool MyDrawing::draw_circle(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context> &cr) {
    std::cout << "signal square" << std::endl;

    cr->save();
    cr->set_line_width(10);
    cr->set_source_rgba(0., 0., 1., 1.);
    cr->arc(beginPoint_x, beginPoint_y, width, 0, 2 * M_PI);
    cr->stroke();
    cr->restore();

    return false;
}

void MyDrawing::switch_to_circle() {
    isDrawRectangle = false;

}

void MyDrawing::switch_to_rectangle() {
    isDrawRectangle = true;
}
```

When I click another shape, the previous shape keeps being displayed on the drawing area and the new shape is drawn on it. On the other hand, when the signal is disconnected, the corresponding shape also disappears from the screen. How could I make sure the shapes keep being displayed?

Comment: The usual approach is to use a signal handler. Why would you want to avoid it? Also, your code snippet does not involve a drawing area, could you please update it to give a minimum of context as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You need a bit more context so that we know which `get_width()` and `get_height()` functions are being used and which drawing area is supposed to display the drawing. *(If this is intended to be part of a member function, define just enough of your class for the syntax to make sense. That would include the member function and an indication of when you plan to call it.)*

Comment: Thats an improvement, however there is *a lot* of code here most of which seems noise for the problem at hand. Would you be able to post a minimal and reproducible example please. One which the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem which we could build and study?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what made you inherit from `Gtk::Layout` instead of using a standard `Gtk::DrawingArea`, but I created a simplified (and working) example using a design similar to yours.

The basic idea is that when the user is done drawing a shape (stops the drag and releases the mouse button), the following happens:

1. The current state of the window (in terms of what is drawn on it) is saved to a `Gtk::Pixbuf`.
2. That `Gtk::PixBuf` is painted on the window.

This means that in 1., the last drawn shaped is also saved in the buffer. When 2. happens, is repainted on the window and hence does not go away. Here is the code, which you will need to adapt a bit to your case. First, a draw helper:

```cpp
class DrawHelper : public Gtk::Layout
{

public:

    DrawHelper();
    ~DrawHelper();

private:

    bool draw_image(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context>& p_context);
    bool draw_rectangle(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context>& p_context);
    bool add_current_shape(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context>& p_context);

    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> m_buffer;

    double m_startX;
    double m_startY;

    double m_endX;
    double m_endY;

    double m_width;
    double m_height;

    sigc::connection m_drawConnection;
};
```

which is responsible to do the actual drawing and handle connections. It is implemented like so:

```cpp
DrawHelper::DrawHelper()
{
    // Create a pixel buffer containing the background image:
    m_buffer = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("file.svg", DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &DrawHelper::draw_image));

    // Enable signals:
    add_events(Gdk::BUTTON1_MOTION_MASK | Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | Gdk::BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK);

    // Save initial pointer position when clicked:
    signal_button_press_event().connect(
        [this](GdkEventButton* p_event)
        {
            m_startX = p_event->x;
            m_startY = p_event->y;

            return true;
        });

    // Update rectangle when mouse is dragged:
    signal_motion_notify_event().connect(
        [this](GdkEventMotion* p_event)
        {
            m_endX = p_event->x;
            m_endY = p_event->y;

            m_width  = m_endX - m_startX;
            m_height = m_endY - m_startY;

            signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &DrawHelper::draw_rectangle));
            queue_draw();

            return true;
        });

    // Change background so it includes the shape just drawn by
    // the user:
    signal_button_release_event().connect(
        [this](GdkEventButton* p_event)
        {
            // Notice we save to connection to later disconnect it:
            m_drawConnection = signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &DrawHelper::add_current_shape));

            return true;
        });
}

DrawHelper::~DrawHelper() = default;

bool DrawHelper::draw_image(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context>& p_context)
{
    Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(p_context, m_buffer, 0, 0);

    p_context->paint();

    return false;
}

bool DrawHelper::draw_rectangle(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context>& p_context)
{
    p_context->save();

    p_context->set_line_width(2);
    p_context->rectangle(m_startX, m_startY, m_width, m_height);
    p_context->stroke();

    p_context->restore();

    return false;
}

bool DrawHelper::add_current_shape(const Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context>& p_context)
{
    // Save the current drawing, including the last drawn
    // shape. This will become the new background (which will
    // visually preserve the last drawn shape).
    m_buffer = Gdk::Pixbuf::create(p_context->get_target(), 0, 0, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(p_context, m_buffer, 0, 0);

    p_context->paint();

    // We disconnect the signal because we do not want it
    // to keep getting called:
    m_drawConnection.disconnect();

    return false;
}
```

Then, a window to hold this helper and display it to the user:

```cpp
class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

public:

    MyWindow();

private:

    DrawHelper m_drawHelper;

};

MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
    set_default_size(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

    // Add draw helper:
    add(m_drawHelper);

    // Show all widgets:
    show_all();
}
```

Then, the main to run it:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
#include <cairomm/context.h>
#include <cairomm/surface.h>

constexpr int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 500;
constexpr int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 500;

// DrawHelper here ...
// MyWindow here ...


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
  
    MyWindow window;
  
    return app->run(window);
}
```

That being said, I would recommend you use a classic `Gtk::DrawingArea` instead and overload the `on_draw` signal handler. This would make all of this easier to understand, and the online documentation would be of more help to you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it was very helpful. Anyway, if anyone has a better solution, i'm happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, I have another solution for you. Instead of saving the already drawn shape on the background image, you could save their parameters directly and redraw them. I have written an example program that does just this:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
#include <cairomm/context.h>
#include <cairomm/surface.h>

constexpr int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 500;
constexpr int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 500;
constexpr double LINE_WIDTH = 2.0;

// Free functions for drawing shapes:
namespace
{

void DrawRectangle(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& p_context,
                   double p_startX,
                   double p_startY,
                   double p_width,
                   double p_height)
{
    p_context->save();

    p_context->set_line_width(LINE_WIDTH);
    p_context->set_source_rgba(0, 0, 1, 1);
    p_context->rectangle(p_startX, p_startY, p_width, p_height);
    p_context->stroke();

    p_context->restore();
}

void DrawCircle(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& p_context,
                double p_startX,
                double p_startY,
                double p_width)
{
    p_context->save();

    p_context->set_line_width(LINE_WIDTH);
    p_context->set_source_rgba(0, 0, 1, 1);
    p_context->arc(p_startX, p_startY, p_width, 0, 2 * M_PI);
    p_context->stroke();

    p_context->restore();
}

}

// Shape interface:
//
//  A shape represents a 2D geometric shape a user can draw on the
//  Drawing area. All shapes implement a 'Draw' method which is where
//  the drawing logic resides.
class IShape
{

public:

    virtual ~IShape() = default;

    virtual void Draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& p_context) = 0;
};

// Rectangle shape:
class Rectangle : public IShape
{

public:

    Rectangle(double p_left, double p_up, double p_width, double p_height)
    : m_left{p_left}
    , m_up{p_up}
    , m_width{p_width}
    , m_height{p_height}
    {}

    void Draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& p_context) override
    {
        DrawRectangle(p_context, m_left, m_up, m_width, m_height);
    }

private:
    
    double m_up;
    double m_left;
    double m_width;
    double m_height;

};

// Circle shape:
class Circle : public IShape
{

public:    

    Circle(double p_cX, double p_cY, double p_radius)
    : m_cX{p_cX}
    , m_cY{p_cY}
    , m_radius{p_radius}
    {}

    void Draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& p_context) override
    {
        DrawCircle(p_context, m_cX, m_cY, m_radius);
    }

private:

    double m_cX;
    double m_cY;
    double m_radius;
};

// Draw helper:
//
//  This class represents the widget onto which the user can drawn. Under
//  the hood, this is a Gtk::Drawing area with some signal handlers defined
//  to draw shapes on user action.
//
//  All drawing occurs in the 'on_draw' method, and all signal handlers to
//  is to handle the data (e.g positions, dimentsions, etc) for the 'on_draw'
//  method to work appropriately.
//
//  The 'SetCurrentShape' method can be used to tell the helper which shape
//  to draw.
class DrawHelper : public Gtk::DrawingArea
{

public:

    enum class Shape
    {
        None,
        Rectangle,
        Circle,
    };

    DrawHelper()
    {
        add_events(Gdk::BUTTON1_MOTION_MASK | Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | Gdk::BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK);

        // Click, drag and release signal handlers:
        signal_button_press_event().connect(  [this](GdkEventButton* p_event){return OnButtonPressed(p_event);} );
        signal_motion_notify_event().connect( [this](GdkEventMotion* p_event){return OnMouseMotion(p_event);}   );
        signal_button_release_event().connect([this](GdkEventButton* p_event){return OnButtonReleased(p_event);});
    }

    void SetCurrentShape(Shape p_shape)
    {
        m_currentShape = p_shape;
    }

private:

    // All drawing occurs here and only here:
    bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& p_context) override 
    {
        // Draw background:
        if(!m_buffer)
        {
            m_buffer = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("file.svg", DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        }

        Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(p_context, m_buffer, 0, 0);
        p_context->paint();

        // Draw previously drawn shapes:
        for(const auto& shape : m_alreadyDrawn)
        {
            shape->Draw(p_context);
        }

        // Draw current shape:
        if(m_currentShape == Shape::Rectangle)
        {
            DrawRectangle(p_context, m_startX, m_startY, m_width, m_height);
        }

        if(m_currentShape == Shape::Circle)
        {
            DrawCircle(p_context, m_startX, m_startY, m_width);
        }


        return false;
    }

    bool OnButtonPressed(GdkEventButton* p_event)
    {
        m_startX = p_event->x;
        m_startY = p_event->y;

        return true;
    }

    bool OnMouseMotion(GdkEventMotion* p_event)
    {
        m_endX = p_event->x;
        m_endY = p_event->y;

        m_width  = m_endX - m_startX;
        m_height = m_endY - m_startY;

        queue_draw();

        return true;
    }

    bool OnButtonReleased(GdkEventButton* p_event)
    {
        if(m_currentShape == Shape::Rectangle)
        {
            m_alreadyDrawn.push_back(std::make_unique<Rectangle>(m_startX, m_startY, m_width, m_height));
        }

        if(m_currentShape == Shape::Circle)
        {
            m_alreadyDrawn.push_back(std::make_unique<Circle>(m_startX, m_startY, m_width));
        }

        return true;
    }

    Shape m_currentShape = Shape::None;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> m_buffer;

    double m_startX;
    double m_startY;

    double m_endX;
    double m_endY;

    double m_width;
    double m_height;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IShape>> m_alreadyDrawn;

};

// Main window:
//
//  This window holds all widgets. Through it, the user can pick a shape
//  to draw and use the mouse to draw it.
class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

public:

    MyWindow()
    : m_drawRectangleBtn{"Rectangle"}
    , m_drawCircleBtn{"Circle"}
    {
        set_default_size(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

        m_headerBar.set_show_close_button(true);
        m_headerBar.pack_start(m_drawRectangleBtn);
        m_headerBar.pack_start(m_drawCircleBtn);;
        set_titlebar(m_headerBar);
        add(m_drawArea);

        m_drawRectangleBtn.signal_clicked().connect([this](){OnRectangleBtnClicked();});
        m_drawCircleBtn.signal_clicked().connect([this](){OnCircleBtnClicked();});

        show_all();
    }

private:

    Gtk::HeaderBar m_headerBar;
    Gtk::Button    m_drawRectangleBtn;
    Gtk::Button    m_drawCircleBtn;
    DrawHelper     m_drawArea;

    void OnRectangleBtnClicked()
    {
        m_drawArea.SetCurrentShape(DrawHelper::Shape::Rectangle);
    }

    void OnCircleBtnClicked()
    {
        m_drawArea.SetCurrentShape(DrawHelper::Shape::Circle);
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
  
    MyWindow window;
  
    return app->run(window);
}
```

Each time the user releases the mouse button, the drawn shape is saved (with the parameters at the time of the release) into an `std::vector` as an `IShape`, which has a `Draw`,  method. This method can later be called to redraw the shape. Then, in the `on_draw` handler, all previously drawn shapes are redrawn, leaving them on the screen. Note that I have used a `Gtk::DrawingArea` here, which is more typical than your approach. I wanted to show you that alternative which, in my opinion, makes cleaner code (no messing around with the handler callbacks).

On a final note, possible enhancements are possible with this (there are more, theses are just some I was thinking about while writing this):

- You could reduce performance costs by caching some stuff instead of redrawing everything every time.
- You could reduce performance costs by using parameters in the calls to `queue_draw` so that the whole widget is not constantly redrawn (only the part that changed).
- You could use a factory to create the shapes. This would decouple the shape creation from the rest of the code, which would only know the `IShape` interface. It would also make you program easier to maintain if you ever want to add shapes.

Comment: Thank you for your tips and your solution, but every time i run it, i get this error:  `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

Comment: Oh... I'll check it out next time I can.

Comment: Did you add a picture file named `file.svg` in the same directory as the executable before running it?

Comment: yes. i do. and if problem related to the file and etc , this error occurs: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Glib::FileError'`

Comment: Ok, I built this on Ubuntu using `g++` version 9.3.0. I can run it and everything works as expected. This sounds like their is undefined behavior somewhere. If you can give me a little bit more information, we could debug it, but from here it is kind of hard as I can't reproduce. Does the segfault happens as you start the program or you have to do some action for it to happen?

Comment: Also, on what setup are you building and running this?

Comment: I just compiled in (same machine) using `clang` and I still does not experience the segfault you are referring to. I guess I am out of luck.

Comment: I run the program using cmake in clion idea.
And I did not change it except the image path.